# Laravel 9 Composer Require Failed = Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: livereload, laravel-9, autoreload

*I apologize in advance because I have created a thread with a similar title to another thread. I had to do this because I couldn't find a way to fix this.*

So, I want to make my website auto reload/refresh using the Laravel Serve LiveReload by Bangnokia library (src: https://github.com/bangnokia/laravel-serve-livereload) following the tutorial from Gubug IT's yt channel (src: [https: //www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJ7m6fWNW0E](https://https:%20//www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJ7m6fWNW0E)).

Well, when I install `composer require bangnokia/laravel-serve-livereload --dev` on laravel 9, an error appears like the photo below. maybe colleagues have a solution to fix this or suggest a solution with another method. please help me, thank you..

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yap2o.png)

my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.4",
        "google/recaptcha": "^1.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel-lang/lang": "~3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.2",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.5",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
        "realrashid/sweet-alert": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This package is daed, please use the new Vite integrated instead.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#blade-refreshing-on-save

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).